# Vertex AI Tensorboard trough user interface

Tags: tensorboard, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have been using the Vertex AI training service with a custom container for my own machine learning pipeline. I would like to get tensorboard logs into the experiments tab to see in real-time the metrics while the model is training.

I was wondering if it is possible to set a custom training job in the user interface setting a `TENSORBOARD_INSTANCE_NAME`. It seems that this is only possible through a json-post-request.

Comment: Could you please look at [Vertex Ai](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/gcp/vertex_pipelines_vertex_training) and [TENSORBOARD_INSTANCE_NAME](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/tensorboard-overview), let us know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I have already saw the tensorboard section in vertex. My question is how to create a custom training job (using the vertex user interface) specifying the tensorboard instance name. According to this guide, it is only possible with a post request [vertex-with-custom-training-jon](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/tensorboard-training#create_a_custom_training_job)

Comment: Perhaps I read the doc differently, but it seems that the post example is about referring to an existing name rather than creating a new one. I don't see a way to create the name in the UI but am also not sure it is possible via the linked instructions.